# What is wrong with my text based game?

Tags: java

So I am making a text based game and when I run the game and choose my class (Knight, Mage or Archer), it gives me 100, 100, 100.

What's wrong?

Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdventureText {
  public static void main(String[] main) {

    String namePlr;
    String classPlr;
    int healthPlr;
    int magickaPlr;
    int staminaPlr;
    int maxHealthPlr;
    int maxMagickaPlr;
    int maxStaminaPlr;

    instructions();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);     //Reader

    console("What is your name?");
    namePlr = in.nextLine();

    console("What class are you? Knight, Mage or Archer?");
    classPlr = in.nextLine();

    if (classPlr == "Knight") {     
      healthPlr = 200;
      magickaPlr = 100;
      staminaPlr = 150;
      maxHealthPlr = 200;
      maxMagickaPlr = 100;
      maxStaminaPlr = 150;
      console("Your stats are");
      console("Max Health: " + maxHealthPlr);
      console("Max Magicka: " + maxMagickaPlr);
      console("Max Stamina: " + maxStaminaPlr);         
    } else if (classPlr == "Mage") {         
      healthPlr = 100;
      magickaPlr = 200;
      staminaPlr = 150;
      maxHealthPlr = 100;
      maxMagickaPlr = 200;
      maxStaminaPlr = 150;
      console("Your stats are");
      console("Max Health: " + maxHealthPlr);
      console("Max Magicka: " + maxMagickaPlr);
      console("Max Stamina: " + maxStaminaPlr);      
    } else if (classPlr == "Archer") {          
      healthPlr = 150;
      magickaPlr = 100;
      staminaPlr = 200;
      maxHealthPlr = 150;
      maxMagickaPlr = 100;
      maxStaminaPlr = 200;    
      console("Your stats are");
      console("Max Health: " + maxHealthPlr);
      console("Max Magicka: " + maxMagickaPlr);
      console("Max Stamina: " + maxStaminaPlr);
    } else {
      console("Oh, you are nobody. So...");
      console("Brawler suits you");
      healthPlr = 100;
      magickaPlr = 100;
      staminaPlr = 100;
      maxHealthPlr = 100;
      maxMagickaPlr = 100;
      maxStaminaPlr = 100;      
      console("Your stats are");
      console("Max Health: " + maxHealthPlr);
      console("Max Magicka: " + maxMagickaPlr);
      console("Max Stamina: " + maxStaminaPlr);
    }

  }
  public static void console(String write) {

    System.out.println(write);

  }
  public static void instructions() {

    console("Hello and welcome to Adventure Text.");
    console("WARNING: This game is caps sensitive. Always start input line with a capital letter!!!");

  }

}
```

Comment: as a sidenode to the answer in the duplicate question. use `equalsIgnoreCase` if you want your game to be not case sensitive.

Comment: Excuse me, this is a duplicate of "How do I compare Strings". But I cannot flag it as that? Why?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi already closed ;)

Comment: @KevinEsche. Oh, It didn't show me, until I reloaded the page.